# AngularJS $routeProvider is there a shorthand way of having multiple routes with same settings?

Tags: angularjs

I have both routes leading to the same view and controller (i.e. I'm just passing in an id to access in $routeParams and performing controller logic on it):

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/about',
        {
            controller: 'AboutController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            templateUrl: 'about.html'
        })
        .when('/about/:id',
        {
            controller: 'AboutController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            templateUrl: 'about.html'
        });
```

This feels very repetitive. Is there any shorthand, something like this?

```
$routeProvider
            .when(['/about', '/about/:id'],
            {
                controller: 'AboutController',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                templateUrl: 'about.html'
            })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From `$routeProvider` source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngRoute/route.js#L23), it seems to me that it is not possible. `this.when` method accepts two parameters, `path` and `route`. For multiple path, `this.when` should either accept array of path as parameter, or extract multiple paths from single string. I don't see any of these two in this method.

```
this.when = function(path, route) {
    //copy original route object to preserve params inherited from proto chain
    var routeCopy = angular.copy(route);
    if (angular.isUndefined(routeCopy.reloadOnSearch)) {
      routeCopy.reloadOnSearch = true;
    }
    if (angular.isUndefined(routeCopy.caseInsensitiveMatch)) {
      routeCopy.caseInsensitiveMatch = this.caseInsensitiveMatch;
    }
    routes[path] = angular.extend(
      routeCopy,
      path && pathRegExp(path, routeCopy)
    );

    // create redirection for trailing slashes
    if (path) {
      var redirectPath = (path[path.length - 1] === '/')
            ? path.substr(0, path.length - 1)
            : path + '/';

      routes[redirectPath] = angular.extend(
        {redirectTo: path},
        pathRegExp(redirectPath, routeCopy)
      );
    }

    return this;
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

> This feels very repetitive. Is there any shorthand,...

You cannot have multiple values for the first(**path**) parameter of `.when()`.

But you can reduce your code by considering the fact that the second parameter(**route**) is an object.

So, change your code from this:

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/about',
        {
            controller: 'AboutController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            templateUrl: 'about.html'
        })
        .when('/about/:id',
        {
            controller: 'AboutController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            templateUrl: 'about.html'
        });
```

to this:

```
var aboutControllerRC = {
                controller: 'AboutController',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                templateUrl: 'about.html'
            };

    $routeProvider
            .when('/about', aboutControllerRC)
            .when('/about/:id', aboutControllerRC);
```

Comment: I used this implementation, but after minify it doesn't work.